# Identifying $X^2$ relationships between random variables

Tags: probability-or-statistics, visualization

Given $X$ coming from a known distribution faily, how do I identify distribution family of of $X^2$ and $\sqrt{X}$?

Code below uses `TransformedDistribution[(x^2),...]` and succeeds to find distribution of $X^2$ for $X$ coming from `Uniform`, `Rayleigh`, but fails for some other pairs (Chi should become $\chi^2$, squared Wigner Semi-circle is Marchenko-Pastur).

For $\sqrt{X}$, this approach always fails. Any tips how to make this more robust?

```
vars = {{"Uniform", UniformDistribution[]}, {"Beta", 
    BetaDistribution[1/2, 1]}, {"Triangle", 
    TriangularDistribution[]}, {"Kumaraswamy(2,3)", 
    KumaraswamyDistribution[2, 3]}, {"ArcSin", 
    ArcSinDistribution[]}, {"Pareto(1,2)", 
    ParetoDistribution[1, 2]}, {"InverseGamma", 
    InverseGammaDistribution[1, 2]}, {"Inverse Normal", 
    InverseGaussianDistribution[2, 1]}, {"Frechet(2,1,0)", 
    FrechetDistribution[2, 1, 0]}, {"Semi-circle", 
    WignerSemicircleDistribution[2]}, {"Marchenko-Pastur", 
    MarchenkoPasturDistribution[1]}, {"Weibull", 
    WeibullDistribution[1/2, 4]}, {"Tracy-Widom", 
    TracyWidomDistribution[1]}, {"Extreme Value", 
    ExtremeValueDistribution[]}, {"Voigt(1,1)", 
    VoigtDistribution[1, 1]}, {"Rayleigh(1)", 
    RayleighDistribution[1]}, {"Erlang(1,2)", 
    ErlangDistribution[2, 1]}, {"Gamma(1,2)", 
    GammaDistribution[1, 2]}, {"Bates(3)", 
    BatesDistribution[3]}, {"Gumbel", GumbelDistribution[]}, {"Chi", 
    ChiDistribution[1]}, {"Von-Mises", 
    VonMisesDistribution[0, 1/2]}, {"ChiSquared", 
    ChiSquareDistribution[1]}, {"MaxwellDistribution(1/2)", 
    MaxwellDistribution[1/2]}, {"Student-T", 
    StudentTDistribution[1]}, {"Exponential", 
    ExponentialDistribution[1/2]}, {"Normal", 
    NormalDistribution[]}, {"Pareto(1,2)", 
    ParetoDistribution[1, 2]}, {"Cauchy", 
    CauchyDistribution[]}, {"Logistic", 
    LogisticDistribution}, {"Von-mises", 
    VonMisesDistribution[0, 1/2]}, {"Hotelling(1,30)", 
    HotellingTSquareDistribution[1, 30]}, {"F-ratio", 
    FRatioDistribution[1, 1]}, {"Gamma[1,4,1/2,0]", 
    GammaDistribution[1, 4, 1/2, 0]}, {"BetaPrime", 
    BetaPrimeDistribution[1/2, 1/2, 1, 1]}, {"Laplace", 
    LaplaceDistribution[]}, {"Sech", 
    SechDistribution[]}, {"Exponential Power", 
    ExponentialPowerDistribution[1]}, {"ShiftedGompertzDistribution", 
    ShiftedGompertzDistribution[1, 1/2]}, {"Moyal", 
    MoyalDistribution[]}, {"Landau", LandauDistribution[]}, {"Levy", 
    LevyDistribution[0, 1]}, {"Suzuki", 
    SuzukiDistribution[2, 1]}, {"Rice", 
    RiceDistribution[0, 2]}, {"Hoyt", 
    HoytDistribution[1, 2]}, {"K-distribution", 
    KDistribution[2, 2]}, {"Beckman", 
    BeckmannDistribution[1, -2, 2, 1]}, {"Nakagami", 
    NakagamiDistribution[1, 3]}, {"Meixner", 
    MeixnerDistribution[2, 0, 0, 1]}, {"Voigt(1,1)", 
    VoigtDistribution[1, 1]}, {"Log-Gamma", 
    LogGammaDistribution[2, 1, 1]}, {"Exp-Gamma", 
    ExpGammaDistribution[1, 2, 1]}, {"Hotelling", 
    HotellingTSquareDistribution[1, 30]}};
format[expr_] := 
  If[Head@expr === TransformedDistribution, "~", Head@expr];
TableForm[{format@Last[#], 
    format@TransformedDistribution[x^2, x \[Distributed] Last@#], 
    TransformedDistribution[x^(1/2), 
     x \[Distributed] 
      TruncatedDistribution[{0, \[Infinity]}, Last@#]]} & /@ vars, 
 TableHeadings -> {{}, {"X", "X^2", "X^(1/2)"}}]
```

Motivation: a diagram like [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relationships_among_probability_distributions) but for $X^2\leftrightarrow X \leftrightarrow  \sqrt{X}$ relationship.

Comment: What version of *Mathematica* are you using?  `TransformedDistribution[x^2, x \[Distributed] ChiDistribution[v]]` works to give a `ChiSquareDistribution[v]` in 13.3.

Comment: Given that you start with all distributions with that deal with real numbers, why would you expect a real result from the square root of a Normal distribution?

Comment: I was using 13.2. So negative numbers would be an issue, need to use `TruncatedDistribution` for that part. Modified code, but it still struggles to identify any of the known square root families

Comment: Can you give an example of a known square root family?  I'm not saying there aren't any but I think you need to give specifics in your question.

Comment: So if square of Chi, Semicircle, Uniform produce Chi2, Marchenko-Pastur, Beta, it would be nice to have something to go the other way -- given Marchenko-Pastur, identify that it is WignerSemicircle squared

Comment: `TransformedDistribution[Sqrt[x], x \[Distributed] ChiSquareDistribution[v]]` works in 13.3.  If you're compiling a list to complain to Wolfram about that's great.  So what exactly are you asking?  Are you asking for us to create that list?  Or are there specific distribution where you'd like a workaround?  And by workaround, maybe using `Assumptions` or `TruncatedDistribution` is a solution.  (I know it probably doesn't sound like it but I'm in full support of having such conversions work.  I just think you need to be specific with the examples and exactly what you want.)

Comment: @JimB I'm looking to find distribution family pairs related by $X^2$ or $\sqrt{X}$ operation. `TransformedDistribution` finds some of them, need a more robust comparison operation to find more of them.

Comment: @JimB more specifically, something to identify that WignerSemicircleDistribution[2] becomes `MarchenkoPasturDistribution[1]` when squared

Comment: So a messy and slow idea: you could get the PDF of the transformed distribution (e.g. `PDF[TransformedDistribution[x^2, 
  x \[Distributed] WignerSemicircleDistribution[2]]]`) , then also get the mean and variance of the transformed distribution, and then set the distribution parameters for all the families in `vars` s.t. they have the same mean and variance as the transformed distribution. And then find the distribution family in `vars` (if it exists) that has the same pdf as the transformed distribution.

Comment: @kglr good catch